# Is there a particular key to enter one character and exit insert mode in vim vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscodevim

I find myself adding a single letter during edits. Is there any way to add a character and exit insert mode just like replacing `r` but not deleting the character in Vs code vim extension?
pressing `i` `<character>` `<Esc>` each and every time defeats the purpose of being productive.
I have also looked for mapping and tried but not sure how they work.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From normal mode, you can put yourself in insert mode, type a space, exit back to normal mode, then put yourself in replace mode. That way you find your cursor on a blank space in replace mode, where you can simply type the character you want to add.
Here's how to do it (replace "your-desired-mapping-here" by the mapping that you like, for example: **M**)
**vscode vim plugin way: (add this to your settings.json)**

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["<your-desired-mapping-here>"],
        "after": ["i", " ", "<ESC>", "r"]
    }
]
```

**vim way: (add this to your .vimrc)**

```
nnoremap <your-desired-mapping-here> i <esc>r
```

note: please notice the space after **i** in the vim way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I almost got close .mapped escape in the end .I think this should be definitely added as it has many use cases.